# tensorflow object detection API error to train

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 and I have installer tensorflow and now i am trying to install the object detection API.
I have cloned the API from git so it gave me a repository with the following tree: models/research/
From the research repo, i have following all the steps from the official git and i could run the test. Then after that i did:

```
`sudo python setup.py install`
```

I have also compiled from sources the protoc compiler to have the latest version: 3.5.1

I have collected my data and created the tf record and put them in a data repository.
I put the config file in a training repository.
And i copy th data, training and model file repository into the 
   `models/researches/object-detection/`

then i tried to run the train.py script in order to  and train with my own data but i get the following errors and i am really lost and maybe i did something wrong. Does someone has any idea?

```
`python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 92, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "/home/jimmy/Desktop/ObjectDetecAPI/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 92, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 120, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config; No such file or directory
'
   `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 92, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "/home/jimmy/Desktop/ObjectDetecAPI/models/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py", line 92, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 120, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config; No such file or directory`
```

But i am pretty sure that i have a training repository with a config file inside.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below traceback:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config; No such file or directory`
```

It appears the below path to your config file is incorrectly defined.

```
--pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

I would reccomend you use an absolute file path and/or doublecheck you have the correct PYTHONPATH variables setup before you try to train the model.  It could be something as simple as a misspelling in your path or in your PYTHONPATH.

Ubuntu: See the below instruction for setting PYTHONPATH variables prior to using TensorFlow Object Detection API:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath